# Remove duplicate row from view oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have an oracle view with some duplicate data I'm trying to remove those duplicate row from my view :

This my view code :

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW "GLSID"."VW_GLSID_DOCUMENTS" ("ID", "PARENT_ID", "DOCUMENT_TYPE_ID", "AMOUNT") AS 
  SELECT  container.id,
   container.container_id AS parent_id,
   document.document_type_id,
   container.number_of_documents AS amount
   FROM container
   JOIN document ON document.container_id = container.id ;
```

This view gives me this results :

```
ID | PARENT_ID | DOCUMENT_TYPE_ID | Amount
21      23          3                2
21      23          3                2
21      23          3                1
15      26          3                4
```

Can some one help how I can remove duplicate row from this view to get this :

```
ID | PARENT_ID | DOCUMENT_TYPE_ID | Amount
21      23          3                2
21      23          3                1
15      26          3                4
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT` definitely fixes your problem.  Personally, I would want to know why duplicates are appearing, if you don't expect them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the results returned, the easiest way would be to use DISTINCT in your SELECT:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW "GLSID"."VW_GLSID_DOCUMENTS" ("ID", "PARENT_ID", "DOCUMENT_TYPE_ID", "AMOUNT") AS 
  SELECT DISTINCT container.id,
   container.container_id AS parent_id,
   document.document_type_id,
   container.number_of_documents AS amount
   FROM container
   JOIN document ON document.container_id = container.id ;
```

If you discover errors in your document count, you might try this instead:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW "GLSID"."VW_GLSID_DOCUMENTS" ("ID", "PARENT_ID", "DOCUMENT_TYPE_ID", "AMOUNT") AS 
  SELECT container.id,
         container.container_id AS parent_id,
         document.document_type_id,
         SUM(container.number_of_documents) AS amount
   FROM container
   JOIN document ON document.container_id = container.id 
   GROUP BY container.id,
            container.container_id,
            document.document_type_id
```

Comment: I have tried Distinct before but it gave me an empty view but when I closed and reopened the view in SQL developer it display data without duplicate rows Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use **DISTINCT** operator

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW "GLSID"."VW_GLSID_DOCUMENTS" ("ID", "PARENT_ID", "DOCUMENT_TYPE_ID", "AMOUNT") AS 
SELECT DISTINCT container.id,
container.container_id AS parent_id,
document.document_type_id,
container.number_of_documents AS amount
FROM container
JOIN document ON document.container_id = container.id ;
```